# Swift Unit Test empty image

Tags: unit-testing, swift3

I'm trying to test if an image has been set by an imageView extension. I have the test passing when trying to load in from an http url. Now I want to test if the image gets set from an https url.

My current code is:

```
    func test_DateImageLoadedFromHTTPSURL() {

    let expected = expectation(description: "Image from https did load")

    let viewer = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 250))
    viewer.imageFromServerURL(urlString: "https://dummyimage.com/300x250/000/fff.png")

    if viewer.image != nil {
        expected.fulfill()
    } else {
        XCTFail()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 3.0, handler: nil)

}
```

It should work, unless I'm not seeing it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you testing here? The `imageFromServerURL` method? Also, do you know it's taking less than 3 seconds to complete? Also, is that method an asynchronous method? If the method is asynchronous then this will never work. If it's synchronous then it's generally bad and will block the main thread

Comment: The response is pretty much instant, I've also tried 10+ seconds. I'm testing the method which adds the image to the UIImageView. It's also an asynchronous method. I did try dispatching - but that failed the test also

Comment: I realized that the amount of time it takes doesn't really matter. The order in which you are doing things here (I assume the method is async) will not work for what you are trying to test.

Comment: Ok, How can I test an async method via checking if the image != nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that you are doing things here will never work. Your method is asynchronous here so the order of things happening will be something like...

1. Run the method to get the image
2. Check the `imageView.image` is not nil (it is still nil at this point)
3. Wait for expectations
4. Download of image finished
5. Set the image

The method is asynchronous so the order of things happening changes.

You need to add some sort of completion to your method so that you can check the image is not nil AFTER it has been set and the completion been called.

Like...

```
viewer.imageFromServerURL(urlString: "https://dummyimage.com/300x250/000/fff.png") {
    // image has finished loading here...
    // check the image is not nil
}
```

Of course, you will need to update the actual method so that it will accept a closure and run the closure once the image is loaded.